# How to correctly save a state in storage and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am struggling with creating a feature in my Angular 14 an Ionic 6 app. I wish to make an “Welcome” screen in my app that appears only the first time that the user has opened an app and then never again.

I don’t know how to save that state that the users screen has already been seen by the user and the app should not load it upon second time opening the app…

My idea was to make a storage service that saves the state and then have a route guard that handles redirection and page showing...

I am now receiving this error and have no idea how to fix it... Am I ever corectly storing the value in the storage service or is my code totely wrong?
ERROR:

> Error: src/app/guards/first-load.guard.ts:17:50 - error TS2339:
> Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'. [ng]  [ng] 17
> this.storageService.getValue('first_time').then((value) => { [ng]

My code is bellow:

**storage.service.ts:**

```
export class StorageService {
  constructor(
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    await this.storage.create();
  }
  setValue(key: 'first_time', value: 'done') {
    this.storage.set(key, value);
  }

  getValue(key: 'first_time') {
    this.storage.get(key).then((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
}
```

and here in the first-load.guard.ts I am calling this service:

```
export class FirstLoadGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):  Promise<boolean>
  {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storageService.getValue('first_time').then((value) => {
        if (value !== null) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          resolve(false);
        }
        else {
          this.storageService.setValue('first_time', 'done');
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

If I need to provide more code feel free to just leave me a comment :) I wish someone could help me

Comment: You need to be using async/await on your methods. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage

Comment: FYI there's a nice implementation [here](https://github.com/nartc/ng-conduit/blob/main/src/app/shared/data-access/local-storage.service.ts) though I'd add runtime validation with something like `zod` to ensure data is as expected and typed accordingly. Don't trust data on the boundaries of your application and then use typescript internally

Answer (score 2):

you have problem in your functions definitions. `:` is for declaring format, you are defining variables as constants and that's probably why you are getting null.

change
 `key: 'first_time'` and `value: 'done'`  in your `storage` service to `key: string` and `value: string`. or if you want to have a default value for your functions input:

```
getValue(key: string = 'first_time')
```

or if your inputs are really constant and are not inputs at all, you'd better define them in your service instead of taking inputs:

```
key= 'first_time';
value= 'done';
setValue() {
    this.storage.set(this.key, this.value);
  }

getValue() {
    this.storage.get(this.key).then((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error message

> Error: src/app/guards/first-load.guard.ts:17:50 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'. [ng] [ng] 17
> this.storageService.getValue('first_time').then((value) => { [ng]

is because your `storageService.getValue()` does not actually return anything. To fix this error you need to return the promise with the value from the storage:

```
  getValue(key: 'first_time') {
    return this.storage.get(key).then((value) => {
      console.log(value);
      return value;
    });
  }
```

If you can drop the `console.log()` it can be shorter:

```
  getValue(key: 'first_time') {
    return this.storage.get(key);
  }
```

---

Additionally some more comments on your code:

As [@AmirAli Saghaei wrote in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921834/how-to-correctly-save-a-state-in-storage-and-retrieve-it/75931615#75931615) you're currently declaring the *types* of the function arguments as static *values*, i.e., calling `setValue()` with any other argument values as `first_time` and `done` would give you a type error while compiling. This is most probably not what you want.

If you wanted to provide default values for the arguments use `=` instead of `:`:

```
  setValue(key = 'first_time', value = 'done') {
    // ...
  }
```

If you want to specify the expected type you should use `string`:

```
  setValue(key: string, value: string) {
    // ...
  }
```

Since `init()` is only called synchronously by the constructor it makes no difference using `async`/`await` here. You would have to `await` it in the constructor for which the constructor would have to return a promise - [which is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise).

In the route guard you don't need to create a `new Promise()` but you can just chain and return the promise from `getValue`:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean>
  {
    return this.storageService.getValue('first_time').then((value) => {
      if (value !== null) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return false;
      }
      else {
        this.storageService.setValue('first_time', 'done');
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Or using `async` / `await`:

```
  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean>
  {
    const value = await this.storageService.getValue('first_time');
    if (value !== null) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      this.storageService.setValue('first_time', 'done');
      return true;
    }
  }
```

So a more simplified version of your code could be:

```
export class StorageService {
  constructor(
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.storage.create();
  }

  setValue(key: string, value: string) {
    this.storage.set(key, value);
  }

  getValue(key: string) {
    return this.storage.get(key);
  }
}
```

```
export class FirstLoadGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean>
  {
    const value = await this.storageService.getValue('first_time');
    if (value !== null) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      this.storageService.setValue('first_time', 'done');
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```